# Django & css : Apply Css on a django form field

Tags: css, django, django-forms

I have the modelForm that contains one field :

```
class sarlform(forms.ModelForm):
      denomination_social=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'onkeyup':'this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()'}),required = False)
```

I need to apply a css code on this field, to do so , I added `'class':'test'` to my field `attrs` .

```
class sarlform(forms.ModelForm):
          denomination_social=forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'test','onkeyup':'this.value=this.value.toUpperCase()'}),required = False)
```

`test` is a css class defined as follow :

```
.test{
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

However Nothing happens on my field, Css doesn't work , and I dont know why?
THANK YOU IN ADVANCE

Comment: `defined as follow` - defined where? Inside some .css file?

Comment: yes inside a css file

Comment: can you see your class on the html input?

Comment: yes it's on my html input

Comment: How do you plug this css file to the page? What do STATIC_FILES settings look like? When you open css file URL in a browser - what error message do you see?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I load my STATIC_FILES normally . I dont think the problem in loading static files because other classes on other files work perfectly

Comment: I assume everything is fine then. Given information does not demonstrate any issues.

Comment: that's why I am very confused. everything is logically correct. cant you tell me if there is another way to add css to django form Fields ,please?

Comment: Right click on html element, "inspect", examine "styles" and "computed" tabs at the right pane.